# Truly vectorized routines in python?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, vectorization

Are there really good methods in Python to vectorize matrix like data constructs/containers -operations? What are the according data constructs used?

(I could observe and read that pandas and numpy element-wise operations using vectorize or applymap (may also be the case of apply/apply along axis for rows/columns) are not much of a speed progress compared to for loops. 
Given that when trying to use them, you have sometimes to mess with the specificities of the datatypes when it is usually a little bit easier in for loops, what are the benefits? Readability?)

Are there ways to achieve a gap of performance similar to what happens in Matlab when comparing for loops and vectorized operations?

(note it is not to bash numpy or pandas, these are great, whole matrix operations are ok, it is just that when you have to do element-wise operations, it becomes slow).

EDIT to explain the context:
I was only wondering because I received more than once answers mentionning the fact that apply and so on are actually similar to for loops. That's why I was wondering if there were similar functions implemented in such way that it would perform better. The actual problems were varied. They just had to be element-wise, actually, not "doing the sum, product, whatever of the whole matrix". I did a lot of comparisons with differential outputs sometimes based on other matrices, so I had to use complex functions for this. But since the matrices are huge and the implementation depended on "for loop like" mechanisms, in the end I felt that my program would not work well on a more important dataset. Hence my question. But I was not looking for review, only knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a specific example.

Normal per-element MATLAB or Python functions cannot be vectorized in general. The whole point of vectorizing, in both MATLAB and Python, is to off-load the operation onto the much faster underlying C or Fortran libraries that are designed to work on arrays of uniform data. This cannot be done on functions that operate on scalars, either in MATLAB or Python.

For functions that operate on arrays or matrices as a whole (such as mathematical operators, sum, square, etc), MATLAB and Python behave the same. In fact they use most of the same underlying C and Fortran libraries to do their calculations.

So you need to show the actual operation you want to do, and then we can see if there is a way to vectorize it.

If it is working code and you just want to improve its performance, then [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) stack exchange site is probably a better choice.

Comment: I added an edit. In some ways, you answer to my question. I'll let you see my edit, then will accept your answer if you have nothing to add. Thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't change the answer.  This is a fundamental aspect of how vectorized operations work in any language.

Comment: I was pondering again on this topic, and I would like to ask: is there no way to vectorize in Python without relying on Fortran/C hence on SciPy/NumPy/Pandas and similar librairies? I don't get why Python by itself would not be able to manage arrays just like C, actually? It is "impossible by conception", or is it just not done because offloads are better?

Comment: @AndoJurai: doing efficient vectorization requires low-level control of memory, which not only is not available in scripting languages like python and MATLAB, it completely defeats the purpose of using languages like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @TheBlackCat, that was kind of answers I was looking for.